# WorkEtc API Python Script

Tags: python, xml, json, api

I'm trying to make a universal script in Python that can be used by anybody to import/export all sorts of information from/to Work Etc CRM platform. It has all the documentation here: http://admin.worketc.com/xml.

However, I am now a bit stuck. Authentication works, I can call different API methods, but only the ones without parameters. I am new to Python and that's why I can't figure out how to pass the parameters onto that specific method in the API. Specifically I need to export all time sheets. I'm trying to call this method specifically: http://admin.worketc.com/xml?op=GetDraftTimesheets. For obvious reasons I cannot disclose the login information so it might be a bit hard to test for you.

The code itself:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import urllib2
import sys

email = 'email@domain.co.uk'
password = 'pass'
#service = 'GetEmployee?EntityID=1658'
#service = 'GetEntryID?EntryID=23354'
#service = ['GetAllCurrenciesWebSafe']
#service = ['GetEntryID', 'EntryID=23354']
service = ['GetDraftTimesheets','2005-08-15T15:52:01+00:00','2014-08-15T15:52:01+00:00' ]

class workEtcUniversal():
    sessionkey = None

    def __init__(self,url):
        if not "http://" in url and not "https://" in url:
            url = "http://%s" % url
            self.base_url = url

        else:
            self.base_url = url

    def authenticate(self, user, password):
        try:
            loginurl = self.base_url + email + '&pass=' + password
            req = urllib2.Request(loginurl)
            response = urllib2.urlopen(req)

            the_page = response.read()
            root = ET.fromstring(the_page)
            sessionkey = root[1].text
            print 'Authentication successful!'

            try:
                f = self.service(sessionkey, service)
            except RuntimeError:
                print 'Did not perform function!'

        except RuntimeError:
            print 'Error logging in or calling the service method!'

    def service(self, sessionkey, service):

            try:
                if len(service)<2:         
                    retrieveurl = 'https://domain.worketc.com/xml/' + service[0] + '?VeetroSession=' + sessionkey
                else: 
                    retrieveurl = 'https://domain.worketc.com/xml/' + service[0,1,2] + '?VeetroSession=' + sessionkey
            except TypeError as err:
                print 'Type Error, which means arguments are wrong (or wrong implementation)'
                print 'Quitting..'
                sys.exit()

            try:
                responsefile = urllib2.urlopen(retrieveurl)
            except urllib2.HTTPError as err:
                if err.code == 500:
                    print 'Internal Server Error: Permission Denied or Object (Service) Does Not Exist'
                    print 'Quitting..'
                    sys.exit()
                elif err.code == 404:
                    print 'Wrong URL!'
                    print 'Quitting..'
                    sys.exit()
                else:
                    raise

            try:
                f = open("ExportFolder/worketcdata.xml",'wb')
                for line in responsefile:
                    f.write(line)
                f.close()
                print 'File has been saved into: ExportFolder'
            except (RuntimeError,UnboundLocalError):
                print 'Could not write into the file'


client = workEtcUniversal('https://domain.worketc.com/xml/AuthenticateWebSafe?email=')
client.authenticate(email, password)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing a code Consuming API requires resolving few questions:

- what methods on API are available (get their list with names)
- how does a request to such method looks like (find out url, HTTP method to use, requirements to body if used, what headers are expected)
- how to build up all the parts to make the request

## What methods are available

http://admin.worketc.com/xml lists many of them

## How does a request looks like

GetDraftTimesheet is described here http://admin.worketc.com/xml?op=GetDraftTimesheets

and it expects you to create following HTTP request:

```
POST /xml HTTP/1.1
Host: admin.worketc.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://schema.veetro.com/GetDraftTimesheets"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetDraftTimesheets xmlns="http://schema.veetro.com">
      <arg>
        <FromUtc>dateTime</FromUtc>
        <ToUtc>dateTime</ToUtc>
      </arg>
    </GetDraftTimesheets>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

## Building up the request

The biggest task it to build properly shaped XML document as shown above and having elements `FromUtc` and `ToUtc` filled with proper values. I guess, the values shall be in format of ISO datetime, this you shall find yourself.

You shall be able building such an XML by some Python library, I would use `lxml`.

Note, that the XML document is using namespaces, you have to handle them properly.

Making POST request with all the headers shall be easy. The library you use to make HTTP requests shall fill in properly `Content-Length` value, but this is mostly done automatically.

## Veerto providing many alternative methods

E.g. for "http://admin.worketc.com/xml?op=FindArticlesWebSafe" there is set of different methods for the same service:

- SOAP 1.1
- SOAP 1.2
- HTTP GET
- HTTP POST

Depending on your preferences, pick the one which fits your needs.

The simplest is mostly HTTP GET.

For HTTP requests, I would recommend using `requests`, which are really easy to use, if you get through tutorial, you will understand what I mean.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply! I was just wondering. Can I not just create a XML file that looks exactly like this in a text editor and then use that?

Comment: @serg553 Yes, you can use the XML created in editor. But if you want to pass in some parameters, you have to change the xml for each request. Note, that the XML above shall have updated values for "dateTime" to something similar to "2014-06-24T12:01:22" (check API documentation, but it is likely to allow XSD type `xsd:dateTime`.